# Copy wizard or backup and restore for creating a copy of production in development

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to create a copy of the production instance into a newly created development instance of sql 2008 r2. I wanted to know if there is any difference between using a copy wizard and backup restore method to create a copy of the production. If yes then which is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying compressed backups is a fine approach for its simplicity. Make sure to copy also the MSDB and the Master databases if you are copying an instance as that brings the agent tasks and logins/linked server connections with it. Restore first with the Master database in the instance, and when you are done migrating the databases over (use compressed databases to ensure IO speed), you will also have to [copy over the Service Master Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190337.aspx) if you are going to a different domain. You can also drastically increase IO speed by enabling [IFI (instant file initialization)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2009/12/23/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization.aspx) - however **compressing the database before transfer is critical** as it will speed up the transfer of the backup as well as the restore at a minimal cost of server CPU.

**Copy database Wizard cannot be used for system level databases, but allows for more flexibility and scheduling.** To each his own on this note, though for very large databases I would advise compressing it into a .bak

[image]